# what is the value of this trigonometric expression

Tags: trigonometry

I want to find out value of this expression
$$\cos^2 48°-\sin^2 12°$$
Just hint the starting step.Is there any any formula regarding $\cos^2 A-\sin^2 B$?

Comment: @Jerry but there is not any formula I read like ($\cos A-\sin B$)

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe it gets any simpler?

Comment: Yes I believe because it was asked in a exam in 1994

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\cos^{2}(48)-\sin^{2}(12)=\sin^{2}(42)-\sin^{2}(12)=\sin(54)\sin(30)=\dfrac{1}{2(\sqrt{5}-1)}$$

Here we used the formula-$$\sin^{2}(A)-\sin^{2}(B)=\sin(A+B)\sin(A-B)$$ and $\sin(54)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}-1}$

Comment: sorry answer will be$\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{8}$

Answer (score 2):

I've got a formula :
$$\cos(A+B).\cos(A-B)=\cos^2A-\sin^2B$$
so from this formula this question is now easy
$$\cos^248-\sin^212$$
$$\cos60.\cos36$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{8}$$